# Using a FutureBuilder in a Flutter stateful widget with RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter widget which gets data from a server and renders a List. After getting the data, I parse the data and convert it to an internal object in my application, so the function is something like this:

```
Future<List<Data>> getData(Thing thing) async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(MY_URL));
  // do some processing
  return data;
}
```

After that, I've defined a stateful widget which calls this function and takes the future to render a List.

```
class DataList extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DataListState createState() => _DataListState();
}

class _DataListState extends State<DataList> {
  Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<Data> values = snapshot.data;

    if (values.isEmpty) {
      return NoResultsWidget('No results.');
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return values[index];
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = getSomething().then((thing) => getData(thing));

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: data,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return CustomErrorWidget('Error');
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return LoadingWidget();
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return CustomErrorWidget('Error.');
            } else {
              return createListView(context, snapshot);
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the code works just fine in this manner. But, when I try to move my data to be a class variable (of type Future<List>) that I update through the initState method, the variable just never updates. Example code below:

```
class _DataListState extends State<DataList> {
  Future<List<Data>> data;

  ....

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateData();
  }

  void updateData() {
    data = getSomething().then((thing) => getData(thing));
  }

  ....

}
```

I want to add a refresh indicator to update the data on refresh, and to do that I need to make my data a class variable to update it on refresh, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my data part of the state of the stateful widget and have it work. any help or guides to a github code example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the assignment of the `data` variable in `setState` so that Flutter knows the variable changed and rebuilds your widget.

For example:

```
  void updateData() {
    setState(() {
        data = getSomething().then((thing) => getData(thing));
    });
  }
```